# IValueConverter that sets FontWeight and FontStyle

Tags: silverlight, ivalueconverter

How can an IValueConverter return FontWeights.Bold and FontStyles.Italic?

Based on the value, my converter needs to set the textblock to Bold and Italic or just Normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value Converters are intended to convert the result of a Binding operation and cannot return more than one value.

If you want to set FontWeight and FontStyle on your control, you must set a Binding on each and provide two different value converters. - one to convert to FontWeights and one to convert to FontStyles